# How to linearize $z \iff x = y$?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I have a constraint that reads
$z \iff x = y$
where $z$ is a $0$-$1$ variable and $x$,$y$ are non-zero, positive integer variables. I'm managed to formulate equivalence going in the right direction, but not in the left. Does anyone have any idea here?

Comment: Often it will be possible to only implement one direction of the $\iff$: for example, if it's clear that having $z=1$ is "better" for the optimization problem than $z=0$, then it's enough to enforce $z=1 \implies x=y$, because you'd never want to take $x=y$ but $z=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward big-M approach.  Introduce binary variables $u$ and $v$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
-M(1-z) \le x - y &\le M(1-z) \tag1 \\
x - y + 1 &\le M (1-u) \tag2 \\
y - x + 1 &\le M (1-v) \tag3 \\
1 - z &\le u + v \tag4
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $z \implies x=y$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $u \implies x<y$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $v \implies x>y$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $\lnot z \implies (u \lor v)$.

---

A stronger formulation is:
\begin{align}
-Mu + 0z + 1v \le x - y &\le -1u + 0z + Mv \tag5 \\
u + z + v &= 1 \tag6
\end{align}
The three cases are:

- $u \implies -M \le x - y \le -1$, that is $x < y$.
- $z \implies 0 \le x - y \le 0$, that is $x = y$.
- $v \implies 1 \le x - y \le M$, that is $x > y$.

Comment: Do you want $M(1-u)$ and $M(1-v)$ as RHS of (2) and (3)?

Comment: @prubin Yes, of course, thanks.  Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks! I see that the key was to introduce additional Boolean variables to express whether x < y or y < x holds.